# Style Tabs button in codename one

Tags: codenameone

I need to style the Tabs Button area. Am using CSS and am failing to know how to set the UIID of that area so I can style it. Would like to change the Tab title colour to white and the padding of the same tab button.

[image: Tab title eg Tab2 should be white]

Here is my code

```
    Tabs homtabs = new Tabs();
    homtabs.setUIID("Tabs");

    homtabs.addTab("Tab 1", container1);
    homtabs.addTab("Tab 2", new SpanLabel("Some text directly in the tab"));
    homtabs.addTab("Tab 3", new SpanLabel("Some text directly in the tab"));
    homtabs.setTabPlacement(BOTTOM);
    homtabs.setSwipeActivated(false);
    homtabs.getContentPane().setUIID("TabsArea");
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default tab UIID is "Tab" so styling that color to white will work. You can also set it to something else using the method: `setTabUIID`.

As a side note on Android tabs have a border so you might want to override that too when styling.